# How do I use environment variables in a Python program that will be ran by a different user on a different computer?

Tags: python, environment-variables, email-attachments, smtplib, error-logging

I need to submit an assignment for my computer science class and want to use environment variables to store the user name and password for my email address. My program is going to send an email with a .log file attached to my instructors email address, but I don't want to just hard code my email address and password for him to see.

I am using the os library to import my environment variables with my email credentials, the EmailMessage library to create the email, and the smtplib library to send the email. The .log file contains error logs that are caught from different exceptions.

The variables DB_USER and DB_PASS are my computers environment variables and I use environ.get() to retrieve them. I am hoping there is a way to replace these variables.

This is an online class, so after I submit the assignment online he will download my program and run it on his computer for grading, so I need to make sure that my program is able to pull my email username and password to send the email. I know how to create environment variables on my computer to store my email username and password, but I realize that my instructor will not have access to my computers environment variables. Is there a way to do this? Also, I am not sure if this makes any difference, but I am running windows 10 on an asus and my instructor is running linux on an acer.

```
import os
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.message import EmailMessage

def send_email():

    EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
    EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')

    contacts = [EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'secondemail@email.com']

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(contacts)
    msg['Subject'] = 'HEY YOU!'
    msg['Date'] = email.utils.localtime()
    msg.set_content('Yeah you!')

    files = ['filename.log']
    for file in files:

        with open('filename.log', 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
            file_name = f.name
        msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: forget it. To create variables you will have to hardcode these values in code or in some file with settings/congif. I would rather use `input()` to get data from user and instructor should use own email name and password to test it.

Comment: I wish that I could use input() because then I probably would have done something different for the assignment that didn't even involve sending an email, but my instructor told us that for this assignment we can't ask for user input().

Comment: then ask him how to send it without giving him you private email - because it is not secure. OR maybe create new account on Gmail only for tests - and after few month you will delete this account